# Rails Devise Confirmable - redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

The Rails docs for devise say that the instructions for how to redirect are incorrect:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#redirecting-user

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: have you tried `after_confirmation_path_for` ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to override devise confirmation controller.
in your routes.rb add this line

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
```

create file in and paste this code

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  private

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    your_new_after_confirmation_path #your path where you want to land
  end

end
```

you may also need to restart the server.

Source : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#redirecting-user